# Can I make the ModalPopupExtender non modal? - AJAX toolkit

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Is there a way for me to:

1. Use the `ModalPopupExtender` but make it non modal
2. Position the Modal to the bottom right part of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. maybe through editing original CSS, javascript files?
2. http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx, you can set X, Y coordinates.